# Tex4ebook - reference within endnote / footnote reference

Tags: tex4ht, endnotes, tex4ebook

I use references to other endnotes within an endnote.

Example:

```
\usepackage{endnotes}
\renewcommand{\footnote}{\endnote}

...

\footnote{... siehe Fußnote \textsuperscript{\ref{org4b3dd1c}}
```

(tex is generated from org).

If I create the ebook, this gives an error in the epubcheck (in German: "Fragmentbezeichner ist nicht angegeben.") and the linking does not work (the link is not set correctly in the xhtml). I don't really care about the actual linking (see Fußnote xy is enough), but it would be nice if I could keep the references in my tex/org file and if they appear with the right number. In fact, it is already like that - so ok for me - but I have to get rid of the error due to a submission process.

Kind regards
Hartmut

Sorry, I wasn't precise enough - it is about a reference to footnote in a footnote. Your modified example:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{endnotes}
\renewcommand{\footnote}{\endnote}

\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}
\title{Hello world}
\author{Michal}
\maketitle

\section{Hello}
\lipsum[1-2]

\section{Second section}

Some text\footnote{a first footnote \label{org4b3dd1c}}

Some text\footnote{second footnote with ref to first one\textsuperscript{\ref{org4b3dd1c}}}
\lipsum[3-4]

\section{Third section}

\lipsum[5-6]

\theendnotes

\end{document}
```

This leads to an error in the epubcheck.
KR

Answer (score 1):

**Edit:**

The sample TeX document in the updated question contains `\label` inside `\endnote` command. TeX4ht normally supports labels out of the box, but `\endnote` uses low-level way of defining of the labels, so we need to put the destination link by hand. Try the following `.cfg` file:

```
\Preamble{xhtml}
\Configure{enoteformat}
   {\Link{enmark-\endnoteN}{ennote-\endnoteN}} {\EndLink\AnchorLabel}
\begin{document}
\EndPreamble
```

This is copy of configuration from TeX4ht sources, with the addition of the `\AnchorLabel` command. It will insert the destination link for the current label.

This is the generated HTML code for your endnote with `\label`:

```html
<p class='indent'>   <a href='realsamplese2.html#enmark-1' id='ennote-1'>
<sup><span class='cmr-6'>1</span></sup></a>
<a id='x5-4001x1'></a><span class='cmr-8'>a first footnote</span>
</p>
```

`<a id='x5-4001x1'></a>` is the destination, as you can see from the endnote that references it:

```html
<p class='indent'>   <a href='realsamplese2.html#enmark-2' id='ennote-2'><sup><span class='cmr-6'>2</span></sup></a><a id='x5-4002x2'></a><span class='cmr-8'>
second footnote with ref to first one</span>
<sup class='textsuperscript'><a href='#x5-4001x1'><span class='cmr-9'>1</span><!-- tex4ht:ref: org4b3dd1c  --></a></sup>
</p>
```

---

**Original answer:**

You didn't provide full example, so it is hard to guess. The following example seems to produce a good result:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{endnotes}
\renewcommand{\footnote}{\endnote}

\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}
\title{Hello world}
\author{Michal}
\maketitle

\section{Hello}\label{org4b3dd1c}
\lipsum[1-2]

\section{Second section}

Some text\footnote{siehe Fußnote \textsuperscript{\ref{org4b3dd1c}}}
\lipsum[3-4]

\section{Third section}

\lipsum[5-6]

\theendnotes

\end{document}
```

Epubcheck doesn't find any error for the resulting Epub file and the link to the section works correctly.

The endnotes section looks like this:

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I have added an example of the issue in my question. KR

Comment: @Hartmut ah, I see. I will look into this later this evening.

Comment: @Hartmut I've updated my answer.

Comment: Thank you, that helped! No errors in the epubcheck and the links work, too.

Comment: @Hartmut that's great! I've updated TeX4ht sources as well, so it should work out of the box in the future, after updates get to TeX distributions.